# JAXB unmarshalling : Ignoring/Converting into String some elements

Tags: string, jaxb, element, unmarshalling

I have a xml of this type :

`<A>`

```
  `<B>`

     `<C>`

        `<D>`

       `</D>`

    `</C>`

 `</B>`
```

`</A>`

My problem is that, i can have an important number of C and D elements that leads to a java heap space memory ( i can't correct this problem with the -Xmx propertie ), but i need to keep the associated data with these elements.

I'd like to know if it is possible with JaxB, to stop the creation of objects after the  element and convert the rest of the data into a string that correspond of the value of the  element.
I hope I'm clear, sorry for my English

Comment: * I'd like to know if it is possible with JaxB, to stop the creation of objects after the element B and convert the rest of the data into a string that correspond of the value of the element B. I hope I'm clear, sorry for my English